# When is it safe to publish after declaring a rospy.Publisher?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, rospy, publisher, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently had a problem on Hydro with publishing a message to a topic I had recently declared. The logic looked like:

```
self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.pub_topic, SchedulerRequests)
self.pub.publish(msg)
```

The message does not appear. But, if I wait a tenth of a second, it works:

```
self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.pub_topic, SchedulerRequests)
rospy.sleep(0.1)
self.pub.publish(msg)
```

The Tutorial has a call to `rospy.ros_init()` between the `Publisher()` and `publish()` calls. That does not work for the class I am writing, because `ros_init()` was called earlier in the main program.

Is there a safe way to check that `self.pub` is ready to send messages?

**Clarification**: the subscriber(s) are already up and running. My problem is that unless I wait a while, no message gets sent.

How do I determine that my own Publish object is ready to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107521/when-is-it-safe-to-publish-after-declaring-a-rospy.publisher?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The not satisfying answer is: you don't know. ROS does not provide any mechanism to decide when all potential subscribers have established a connection with your publisher.

You could sleep (as you already suggested) for an unknown amount of time or check the number of current subscribers but actually your node should neither know now care about that. So the recommended way is to write your publish/subscribe application in a way that it can handle this.

If you want to just send one message (e.g. announce a configuration or something similar) you might want to use a latched topic. Every future subscribe will then receive the latest published message.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-12-06**:
Sorry that my question was unclear, Dirk. I am not concerned with the behavior of other nodes. This problem is internal to my sender.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-06**:
It takes some time for all subscribers to actually establish a connection to your new publisher. For you 0.1 seconds might be enough on a local machine if all subscribers are already running but that is not generally the case.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-12-06**:
Yes, the time delay is not an adequate solution. But, `latch=True` seems to close the timing window and causes no harm that I can see. Thanks for the hint, Dirk.